# Checking if a pixel is black in a grayscale image (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I need to figure out if any given pixel is black or white on a gray-scale image that I put through a thresholding algorithm before that. The image becomes basically blobs of black on a white background.

```
Mat falsetest;

...

cv::cvtColor(detected_edges, falsetest, CV_BGR2GRAY);    
threshold(falsetest, falsetest,128, 255,THRESH_BINARY);

...

printf("x:%d y:%d %d\n",x,y,falsetest.at<uchar>(x,y));
```

I expected the results to be either 0 or 255, however, that is not the case. The output for different pixels looks something like this:

```
x:1259 y:175 111
x:1243 y:189 184
x:1229 y:969 203
x:293 y:619 255
x:1123 y:339 183
```

Am I trying to do this in a wrong way, or does it seem that the error lies elsewhere?

Comment: It's difficult to provide an answer for an incomplete code. Your mistake may be in the code that you are not showing us. Read: http://sscce.org/

Comment: After thresholding, how does falsetest look like when you do an imshow?? Only black and white or gray? The code you provide should work, are you sure you didn't change anything when you pasted it here? I am also curious if there is anything suspicious between  threshold and printf

Comment: Yes, the image looks black and white. I don't think there is any suspicious code, but I'll make a separate question with a ssccee as suggested above if I don't manage to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out what the problem was. I thought that when I called

```
cv::cvtColor(detected_edges, falsetest, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

all the matrix data was copied to falsetest. However, it seems that it was not the case, and when I proceeded to modify detected_edges, falsetest also became contaminated. Cloning the matrix solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `falsetest` contains uchar pixels, and not floats? In such case, you would need to access values of `falsetest` by:

```
falsetest.at<float>(x,y)
```

Comment: This results in wildly varying numbers, for example: -96.882393, -26077.882812, -nan, 0.000000, etc., but always negative. Also, why float and not uchar? What property of the matrix defines that?

Answer (score 0):

The CV code looks good. However, you are using %d in printf to display a uchar.

Either use %hhd or do

```
static_cast<int>(falsetest.at<uchar>(x,y)).
```

Comment: Indeed, I had an error there, but it still does not explain why there are completely different pixel values in the image. Shouldn't it be just two?

Comment: well, I was actually guessing that the error was in the display, not in the value itself. A char interpreted as int can lead to unexpected results.